# Modify query to show only patientid not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, sql-null

```
SELECT patientname, patientID
 (CASE WHEN patientid is not null THEN 'yes'
             WHEN patientid is null then 'No'    
        END) as diagnosedornot

FROM database
where diagnosetime between '2020-09-03' and '2020-09-04'
```

Is there a way I can rewrite this query to show only the patientID is not null, I mean to display the data that will only show patientID is not null. What is the best way, using case? Or is that even possible?

I want to optimize this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `where` clause to filter the rows for non-`null` `patientid`s:

```
select patientname
from database
where 
    diagnosetime between '2020-09-03' and '2020-09-04' 
    and patientid is not null
```